# Functional interface and recursion

Tags: java, java-stream, functional-interface

I need to return a function that returns the result of applying the function f to its result n times.
My code:

```
public <T> Function<T, T> fN(Function<T, T> f, int n) {
       return (T t) -> fN(f, n - 1).apply(t);
}
```

When I run the code, I get `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. How would I write this code so it passes the following tests?

```
Function<Integer, Integer> f1 = (x) -> x + 1;
    assertEquals(13, (int)tasks.fN(f1, 13).apply(0));
    assertEquals(2, (int)tasks.fN(f1, 1).apply(1));
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in the debugger?

Comment: Tried. N is minus, and the rest is not monitored, this = "No fields to display" and f = "Class has no fields"

Comment: Your `fN` function doesn't have a stop condition (base case). Presumably, you'd want the code to do something different when `n == 0`, i.e. *not recursing*. E.g. `if (n == 0) return (T t) -> t;`

Comment: Progress is available. But a non-recursive value is returned.

Comment: `assertEquals(13, (int)tasks.fN(f1, 13).apply(0));` java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :13
Actual   :0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non recursive, trivial approach:

```java
public <T> Function<T, T> nonRecursiveFN(Function<T, T> f, int n) {
  return (T t) -> {
      T result = t;
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result = f.apply(result);
      }
      return result;
    };
}
```

If you need to use recursion you need some stop condition as Andreas commented. We can implement it by using internal function that takes already constructed function as argument:

```
public <T> Function<T, T> fN(Function<T, T> f, int n) {
  return fNInternal(f, n, (x) -> x); //we start with identity function
}

public <T> Function<T, T> fNInternal(Function<T, T> f, int remaining, Function<T, T> functionSoFar) {
  //stop condition - that's how we manage to avoid StackOverflow, you were experiencing
  if (remaining == 0) {
    return functionSoFar;
  }
  //here we apply function to the result of all previous applications
  return fNInternal(f, remaining - 1, (T t) -> f.apply(functionSoFar.apply(t)));
}
```

Comment: Or just `public <T> Function<T, T> fN(Function<T, T> f, int n) { return n == 0? x -> x: fN(f, n - 1).andThen(f); }`